# Isomorphic react redux sending Dynamic Id

Tags: reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I am using react router with redux for isomorphic app. I have an use case where href needs to work both on client and server side. This is mainly for SEO reasons. for bots it should use href and when user clicks it should work too

my route looks like this

```
 <Route name="app" component={ProductPage} path="/product/:Id">
      <IndexRoute component={ProductContainer}/>
  </Route>
```

`http://localhost:3000/product/1234` (this works from server side)

Once the above URL renders data, i have page with different URLS of that kind

```
http://localhost:3000/product/3456
http://localhost:3000/product/9999
```

when user clicks the above URLS, i don't want to do a post back, i want to use browserHistory api and render the component, is it possible?

I have this in the container

```
static needs = [
    productActions.getProductData
  ]
```

Any direction will be appreicated

Comment: are you saying that you'd like to render the ProductContainer server side when the user clicks on one of those links?

Comment: Yes correct, it should be render from client side, I think i can do by adding click and dispatch event, but i want to find if there is any better way without click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server Side**

You could require a function call that would do your dispatches onEnter of the specific route, which would populate the app state that you need to render your component.

the route would look something like this:

```
<Route component={ProductPage} path="/product/:Id" onEnter={requireProductData} />
```

`requireProductData` would be a function in your main.js something like this:

```
function requireProductData(nextState, replace, callback) {
    const { params } = nextState
    var idNum = parseInt(params.id.toString().split("-")[0])
    const currentState = store.getState()
    if (idNum > 0) {
        store.dispatch(ProductActionCreators.productInfo({ id: idNum })).then((event) => {
           callback()
        }, (error) => {
           callback()
        })
    } else {
        callback()
    }
}
```

this would do your action creator calls and then your reducer would take care of the app state. then you could render your component from that url.

**Client Side**

Yeah, you're right about doing an onClick handler. Here's an example of where clicking a button causes an API call with a dispatch:

```
class SubscribeUserDialog extends Component {

    subscribeUser(privacy) {
        const { dispatch, readingPlan, auth } = this.props
        if (!auth.isLoggedIn) window.location.replace(`/sign-in`)
        // if user isn't subscribed, then subscribe!
        if (!readingPlan.subscription_id) {
            dispatch(ActionCreators.readingplanSubscribeUser({ id: readingPlan.id , private: privacy }, auth.isLoggedIn)).then(() => {
                // redirect to plan
                this.goToPlan()
            })
        } else {
            // user already subscribed
            this.goToPlan()
        }
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <div className='plan-privacy-buttons text-center'>
                <p className='detail-text'><FormattedMessage id="plans.privacy.visible to friends?" /></p>
                <div className='yes-no-buttons'>
                    <a className='yes solid-button green' onClick={this.subscribeUser.bind(this, false)}><FormattedMessage id="ui.yes button"/></a>
                    <a className='no solid-button gray' onClick={this.subscribeUser.bind(this, true)}><FormattedMessage id="ui.no button" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SubscribeUserDialog
```

In your case, you would have the onClick attached to your links.

Does this help you?

Comment: Thank you, let me give a try

Comment: if this answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? otherwise I will try and help you further!

Comment: may i know how the browser back button going to work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The browser back button will work as normal.